# What does this icon mean?

Tags: notifications

[image]

There is no corresponding notification in the pull-down.

Comment: I assume it means "Ice cream sandwiches are yummy".

Answer (score 1):

If it only happens when the phone is plugged in, I seem to remember this referring to the fact that `Android Debugging` was activated, though I also thought this usually showed a pull-down notification as well. If it only happens when you're plugged into a computer, try un-selecting `Android Debugging` under settings, and see if it goes away.

Comment: You can see the pull down menu version here - http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2011/10/49galaxynexusscreenshot-1319000416.png

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Debugging IS enabled, but I'm not plugged in! :-/

Comment: interesting... if you turn debugging off does it go away?

Comment: Disabling debugging does not remove the icon.  :-/